# <Using SLAM to map areas> Unable to save map

Tags: navigation, slam

I'm working on a tutorial for turtlebot4. And now I'm working on "mapping with SLAM".

I spawned turtlebot4 on an original world different from the tutorial and used the keyboard to move the robot and create a map.
The tutorial site is here, [Generating a map](https://turtlebot.github.io/turtlebot4-user-manual/tutorials/generate_map.html).

After that

```
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_saver_cli -f "map_name" --ros-args -p map_subscribe_transient_local:=true -r __ns:=/namespace
```

I tried to save the map with `__ns:=/namespace` and it could not be saved.
The error is as follows.

```
ros2 run nav2_map_server map_saver_cli -f "map_name" --ros-args -p map_subscribe_transient_local:=true -r __ns:=/namespace
[INFO] [1693187385.273079741] [namespace.map_saver]:. 
    map_saver lifecycle node launched. 
    Waiting on external lifecycle transitions to activate.
    See https://design.ros2.org/articles/node_lifecycle.html for more information.
[INFO] [1693187385.273281899] [namespace.map_saver]: Creating
[INFO] [1693187385.273468424] [namespace.map_saver]: configuring
[INFO] [1693187385.278959365] [namespace.map_saver]: Saving map from 'map' topic to 'curling_sheet' file
[WARN] [1693187385.279017540] [namespace.map_saver]: Free threshold unspecified. Setting it to default value: 0.250000
[WARN] [1693187385.279049089] [namespace.map_saver]: Occupied threshold unspecified.
[ERROR] [1693187387.281892380] [namespace.map_saver]: Failed to spin map subscription
[INFO] [1693187387.285185629] [namespace.map_saver]: Destroying
[ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
```

I would be very grateful for any advice you could give me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have map published on `/namespace/map` topic? It needs to be published there so `map_saver` can receive it.

Probably you have map on `/map` topic. If that is true, starting `map_saver` without `__ns` argument (i.e. with empty namespace) should help